# How to write data into excel in a row/column in Sorted Form- ( i am using JXL ), Used Collection.sort(list) but not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, jxl

I am Not getting ---
I need to Pick list items in E commerce application search box . and Have to Print each Line By line in a column or any number of rows and column, in Excel in sorted form

i am able to get the name of items in the Search and print them in eclipse console.
what can be the logic to Print them one after other in Excel in sorted form , do i need to save them all in an array first or something else .

Here in this Code I am Getting -- Items From the Search box in the E commerce Application and printing them in the Excel.

Need the logic that any random number of search items gets printed in the Excel in sorted Form

i used the code below to print all the search list items in the Column(Excel) ,what change can be made to print them in sorted order

```
// picking list items//     
List <WebElement> listItems = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//form[@class='_1WMLwI']//ul/li"));
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  String[] text = new String[10];
 arrylngth=listItems.size();
 System.out.println("Length of arrylngth" + arrylngth);
 for (int col = 0; col < arrylngth; col++) 
 { text[col]=listItems.get(col).getText();
 System.out.println("Original List "+"                                 "+ text[col]);
// insert data into Excel sheet 
 for (int row = 0; row <1 ; row++) {
// create an empty array list with an initial capacity
List<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>();
 // use add() method to add elements in the list
                 arrlist.add(text[col]);
                 Collections.sort(arrlist);
                 System.out.println("sorted Array "+" "+ arrlist);
for(String counter: arrlist){
System.out.println("After Sorting:"+""+ counter);}
        Label label1 = new Label(row,col,text[col]);

            try {
                shSheet.addCell(label1);
            } catch (RowsExceededException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (WriteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: If you are writing them to the console via System.out.println() why can't you write them directly to Excel using, say, [POI](https://poi.apache.org/)?

Comment: i updated my question, kindly review.. i have to make them print in a sorted manner in Excel. i tried collection.Sort(List) but not worked. i made it to print all in excel but not in sorted manner.

Comment: collection.sort(List) works for int type list not for string type. you are looking to sort search items, is that a number or a name  ??

Comment: its a name (string), example : like in any e commerce application we search for a item name suppose "machine " in the search box , and it gives us a list of similar string like --machine, washing machine, drill machine, Lg washing machine and so on, i have picked that into list and printed it into excel as shown in above code ....now what change i need to make to print the sorted list of those items in excel in ascending or descending

Comment: String[] items = {"washing machine", "drill machine", "LG washing machine"}; Arrays.sort(items);

Answer (score 0):

I got the Answer : 
Step 1: Need to pick the List Web-Elements -

```
List <WebElement> listItems =      driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//form[@class='_1WMLwI']//ul/li"));
```

Step 2: Need To Create a String List where i can store the list elements name ( as collection.sort() applied to sting list)

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Step 3: Apply For Loop to insert data into the String List

```
 for (int i = 0; i <listItems.size(); i++)
    {

    al.add(listItems.get(i).getText());
    System.out.println("Unsorted list " + al);

    }
```

Step 4: Apply Collection.sort() onto the string List , it will Sort the List content

```
Collections.sort(al);
```

step 5: Now there is a need to print the sorted list in the Console\

```
 for (String list:al)
    {
    System.out.println("sorted list"+ "         " + al);
    }
```

as we are done with sorted String list , now its an easy task to write the Sorted list into the Excel using JXL or POI using, Write Excel code.